# Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) crashing while loading XML

Tags: android-studio

Today I updated my Android Studio to the newest stable version `(Arctic Fox 2020.3.1)` and whenever I try to open xml layout, it crashes. I've tried many different things, from rebuilding to invalidating but nothing helped. After upgrade I haven't been able to uninstall Android, because uninstaller was missing (possibly due to crash). I had to restore the system to the point I had an older version. At this point I managed to reinstall Android Studio to the newest version. Even after that the program persisted to crash after trying to open xml (crashes while initializing). At this point I couldn't uninstall again, because the uninstaller is missing (I believe it's due to crash). I had to restore the system again. Any ideas what should I do or did anyone else had the same issue sometimes ago? Thank you in advance. A portion of error is listed below:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000047be3000):  JavaThread "Layoutlib Render Thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8752, stack(0x0000000042430000,0x0000000042530000)]

Stack: [0x0000000042430000,0x0000000042530000],  sp=0x0000000042525f20,  free space=983k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libandroid_runtime.dll+0xb37ff]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(J[JI)I+0
j  android.graphics.HardwareRenderer.syncAndDrawFrame(Landroid/graphics/FrameInfo;)I+13
j  android.graphics.HardwareRenderer$FrameRenderRequest.syncAndDraw()I+8
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(Landroid/view/ViewGroup;Landroid/graphics/HardwareRenderer;)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+18
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(ZZ)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+522
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(Z)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+3
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(JZ)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+49
j  com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(J)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+3
j  com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render()Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+4
j  com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$renderInner$13(Lcom/intellij/psi/PsiFile;)Lcom/android/tools/idea/rendering/RenderResult;+4
j  com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$$Lambda$5038.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run()V+205
J 34329 c2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V java.base@11.0.10 (187 bytes) @ 0x00000000174fd4a8 [0x00000000174fce40+0x0000000000000668]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5 java.base@11.0.10
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 java.base@11.0.10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For Windows**

Replace the existing `libandroid_runtime.dll` at

```
[PATH_TO_STUDIO_DOWNLOAD]/plugins/android/resources/layoutlib/data/win/lib64/
```

with [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/action/issues/195185622/attachments/34461247?download=true).

**For Linux**

Replace the existing `libandroid_runtime.so` at

```
[PATH_TO_STUDIO_DOWNLOAD]/plugins/android/resources/layoutlib/data/linux/lib64/
```

with [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/action/issues/195340081/attachments/34459018?download=true).

**Note:** These files are for Arctic Fox

Sources: [issuetracker.google.com/issues/195340081](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195340081) & [issuetracker.google.com/issues/195185622](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195185622)

Comment: Thanks. As far as I have tested or opened my layout files, I did not encounter any crashes.

Comment: Had the same issue and replacing the DLL worked.

Comment: @ Ferhatwi do you know the file for Mac?