# Android Studio Arctic Fox Crashes after about a minute

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I recently downloaded Arctic Fox for linux and when I create a new Project it crashes after the sync and indexing is completed.
The IDE simply closes automatically and the terminal shows the following dump.

```
$./studio.sh
2021-08-02 17:05:32,668 [  82796]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037 
2021-08-02 17:05:33,032 [  83160]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully 


#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007f254f7f0267, pid=14261, tid=14711
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libandroid_runtime.so+0x630267]
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/oru/java_error_in_studio_14261.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted
```

Log file info:
--------------- T H R E A D --------------- Current thread (0x00007f25d03f7800): JavaThread "Layoutlib Render Thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14711, stack(0x00007f255a293000,0x00007f255a394000)] Stack: [0x00007f255a293000,0x00007f255a394000], sp=0x00007f255a3890f8, free space=984k Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C [libandroid_runtime.so+0x630267]

Why  is this happening? How to solve this?

Comment: Have you looked into `/home/oru/java_error_in_studio_14261.log` as the error suggests?

Comment: Yes. Here is a portion:---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
Current thread (0x00007f25d03f7800):  JavaThread "Layoutlib Render Thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14711, stack(0x00007f255a293000,0x00007f255a394000)]

Stack: [0x00007f255a293000,0x00007f255a394000],  sp=0x00007f255a3890f8,  free space=984k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libandroid_runtime.so+0x630267]

Comment: Edit the question with that code, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Ok. But that's not code it's info and a solution would be more helpful.

Comment: Try using different 11 JDK to run IDE under: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html Also try using different Android SDK version. If the problem remains, report a bug to Android Studio issue tracker: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs

Answer (score 2):

I posted an issue on the issue tracker and had the problem solved (temporarily).
The team member asked me to download a .so file and replace it.
he said -

> The issue is that we compiled that file using a set of CPU instructions not supported by the CPU in your machine.
> The file I attached has been recompiled with not to use those instructions.
> So you can keep using it, it has exactly the same functionalities.
> But we'll make sure to fix the problem in a future release.

Here is the link to the post:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195340081

That will solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that we compiled that file using a set of CPU instructions not supported by the CPU in your machine.

Try to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775289/14998961

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and tried to downgrade android studio - it did not help, all versions of android studio crashed similarly.
Looks like the problem is related to one of Linux packages and not dependent on version of android studio. Using different JDK did not help either.
I using 64-bit Fedora 33 Linux on AMD A8-3870 - probably the problem is specific to Linux distribution or hardware configuration.

As temporary workaround - I disabled layout rendering plugin by removing libandroid_runtime.so binary file from android-studio/plugins/android/resources/layoutlib/data/linux/lib64/ folder.
After that, you will miss "design" and "split" views and will have to use "code" view for modification of layout XML files, but it is better than nothing.