# Android Studio 2020.3.1 x64 wont start

Tags: android-studio

so I got a fresh Windows 10 Pro x64 install 21H1 (OS Built 19043.1266), all drivers and updates installed.
I've downloaded and installed the Android Studio 2020.3.1 for Windows 64-bit but after the install nothing happens.
I tried to run the studio64.exe but it opens and closes.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577130/android-studio-arctic-fox-2020-3-1-crashing-while-loading-xml) to resolve your problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with i would run "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.bat" and see what is the output.

One reason that Android studio wont run is the infamous ASLR.
[Android Studio opening error: Unable to Start Correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536708/android-studio-opening-error-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

A 2nd less known reason is Cleartype on windows, which is incompatible with Java, when you have certain values in the registry.

https://www.rarst.net/software/cleartype-install4j-java-bug/

you can resolve the latter one by pressing the Start button and typing Cleartype, then disable it, and enable it again, go through the tuner.

and try to start Android studio.
or alternatively, open regedit and navigate to "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" find the key "FontSmoothingGamma" and set it to 1000 ( Decimal )

If those dont work, try posting the full output of the studio.bat

Good Luck!

PS, as a matter of fact it affects any Java framework based IntelliJ IDEA PyCharm, webstorm, Arduino IDE or just plain simple Java apps.