# Android Studio - instant crash after single change in the layout (design) window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout, apk

I have an issue with an Android Studio. Every time I'm trying to edit something in the layout\design window (like adding a button or text field, or even changing some text on the label) my Android Studio is instantly crashing without even showing any error message. And for sure it's not a code issue, because I have started to create a simple application from the template (like "hello world") and I don't have any complicated logic in it.

I'm using Android Studio 2020.3.1 on Windows 7. I have Android SDK installed as well.

Solutions I have already tried:

- Run as administrator
- Delete .gradle directory from C:\Users\
- Add something manually in the XML (in the code, not in the layout)
- File > Invalidate caches / restart

Is there any way to see Android Studio crash logs (NOT the application crash logs) and see why it is crashing?
Is there any working solution to this?

Edit: Ok, I need to edit my original question. It seems I can get all logs by clicking "**Settings > Collect logs and Diagnostic Data**".

I can also see the logs in C:\Users\UserName directory right after crash. File is named something like "java_error_in_studio64_5056.log" and it contains this message:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fedfe137ff,
> pid=5056, tid=1488
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build
> 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189) Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc,
> windows-amd64) Problematic frame: C  [libandroid_runtime.dll+0xb37ff]
>
> No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
> client versions of Windows
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp The crash happened
> outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. See problematic frame
> for where to report the bug.

Do someone know how to solve it?

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577130/android-studio-arctic-fox-2020-3-1-crashing-while-loading-xml

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my issue. When I have replaced "libandroid_runtime.dll" file with the one provided in the topic below, everything worked fine.
[Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) crashing while loading XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577130/android-studio-arctic-fox-2020-3-1-crashing-while-loading-xml)

Comment: By the way, if soemone want to find more results in google regarding this issue just use search like this --> "EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION" "libandroid_runtime.dll"